# how to assign specific user roles upon automatic registration - simple FB Connect - Drupal 7

Tags: facebook, templates, drupal-7, registration, fbsdk

How do I assign a specific role from drupal core(D7) upon automatic registration with Simple FB Connect? I currently am using auto role assign and have a custom registration for 2 roles, One is a basic role with limited permissions and the other an advanced role with more edit/creation permissions. My problem is that the simple FB connect link works great but is registering people for the wrong roles. How can I choose the role that is being assigned based on the url?

Maybe something in template.php that would allow the following url to be placed on my facebook buttons?

```
/user/simple-fb-connect?registration=1&role=my_custom_role
```

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use use hook_user_insert and check for the url and assign desired role,

```
     function module_name_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category)
{
         if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] =="url")
        {
        //add code to assign desired role;
        //assuming rid of custom role is 1
        $account->roles[1]='custom_role';
        }
}
```

Comment: this throws an error for me when creating a custom module and adding this to it. I updated the uri to (https://example.com) and rid to '3' but it seems to throw errors on the custom registration page, -'Undefined index'

Comment: Im not sure why this doesnt work, maybe since the simple fb module has to pass over to facebook and then back to the site, that the request url will be facebook.com and not mydomain.com or maybe this only works if the user fills in the fields on the signup page... hard to tell. but yeah it doesnt work.

Comment: If it is redirecting form facebook or any third party URL then also User is registered into your application. Need to verify

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to take a look at the rules module: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/

This module allows you to create automated tasks based on events. What you want to do is:

- Download and enable rules module: https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/
- You'll need to enable rules UI as well
- Go to rules configuration: example.com/admin/config/workflow/rules
- Create a new rule
- The rule event should be something like: "User registers a new account connected to Facebook"
- The rule action should be something like: "Assign role to user"

Interface should be pretty straight forward.
Here's some additional resources:

Rules Handbook
https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/rules

Comment: Yes actually I tried that first, but I also need some condition to be passed into rules to define whether its a "basic" or "editor" user logging in. The only way I can think of doing it is to pass a string in the url and since simple fb connect gives me the possibility of custom landing pages by passing it in the string, I thought that might work but on attempt to register with fb it sends me back to this page `user/simple-fb-connect?editor=#_=_` in my rules condition, I set the path alias to be 'editor' .  didnt work

Comment: You should not allow the user to "chose" his/her role by passing it into the URL, for security reason. You don't want your user to enter the role they want.

Comment: You should have rule send an email to a "moderator" (admin) on your site every time someone register to give him/her the editor role.